# JSSOR "Error: prototype of 'thumbnavigator' not defined"

Tags: jssor

The full JavaScript error is:
Timestamp: 6/4/2015 8:52:37 AM
Error: Error: prototype of 'thumbnavigator' not defined.
Source File: http://webanautics.com/invoice/slider-master/js/jssor.js
Line: 69

I have read the other answers to the same question, but the answers don't work for my particular code.

I'm using the tabs-slider example, [enter link description here](http://www.jssor.com/demos/tab-slider.html)

My Slides Container looks like this:

```
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 29px; width: 900px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid gray; -webkit-filter: blur(0px); background-color: #fff; overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <div style="margin: 10px; overflow: hidden; color: #000;">
            <?php $week = -1; include("includes/invoice-week-module.php"); ?>
            </div>
            <div u="thumb">Last Week</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style="margin: 10px; overflow: hidden; color: #000;">
            <?php $week = 0; include("includes/invoice-week-module.php"); ?>
            </div>
            <div u="thumb">This Week</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style="margin: 10px; overflow: hidden; color: #000;">
            <?php $week = 1; include("includes/invoice-week-module.php"); ?>
            </div>
            <div u="thumb">Next Week</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my thumbnavigator div block:

```
    <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort12" style="left:0px; top: 0px;">
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: default; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-left: 1px solid gray;">
            <div u="prototype" class="p">
                <div class=w><div u="thumbnailtemplate" class="c"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
    </div>
    <!--#endregion ThumbnailNavigator Skin End -->
```

When this error happens, any other JavaScript afterwards doesn't work.

Comment: It looks correct. Would you please leave an url or post full code of your page?

Comment: My apologies, I tried deleting this post, but I was too late by the time you answered. I solved the problem when I realized I had loaded the jssor `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {});` script twice.